# PHP(count()) авторизация на странице

Tags: php, sql

еще у меня есть процесс авторизации на страничке, код:

```
<?php 
    $login = filter_var(trim($_POST['login']), 
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var(trim($_POST['password']), 
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $password = md5($password."ghjsfkld2345");

    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'registerdb');

    $result = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = 
    '$login' AND `password` = '$password'");

    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(count($user) == 0) {
        echo "Такого пользователя не существует...";
        exit();
    }

setcookie('user', $user['name'], time() + 3600, "/");

    $mysql->close();

    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Здесь ↓

```
    $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if(count($user) == 0) {
        echo "Такого пользователя не существует...";
        exit();
    }
```

я хочу проверить наличие пользователя в базе данных, и если его нет(если такого массива, который
я подал при авторизации не будет в базе) то должно появиться просто сообщение:
"Такого пользователя не существует..."
Вместо этого я получаю:
**Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given in E:\php\htdocs\serwis_dla_programistow\auth.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result->fetch_assoc()` возвращает просто информацию о юзере. Я б на Вашем месте использовал `mysqli_num_rows($result)== 0`, который возвращает кол-во строк в БД которые вернул запрос.

А еще сразу после запроса проверяйте его успех:

```
if(!$result) echo $mysql->error;
```